# Best way to create an anonymous mode for logged in users?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a Web App similar to a discussion board and I want to give logged in users the ability to switch to an anonymous mode in which their  username is not displayed but replaced by an ID when they post or reply to a topic. So the question is what is the best way to generate this ID given that :

- A user has the same ID in the same topic.
- The ID for the same user is different from a topic to another.

I'm in a LAMP environment so if you can suggest any PHP function to generate the ID or a way to store it in MySQL database that will be great.

Thanks !

Comment: Wow, that is a lot to ask to suggest a solution for your environment. The anonymous display is a good and simple idea, for that you can use a ternary condition but we need to see some code displaying how you call the user name

Comment: This question is too broad for SO.  You are basically asking for people to architect this solution for you. It might help it you included what efforts you have made to do this or any specific approached you have considered.

Comment: @ Mike Brant I'm asking people if they have encountered the same use case problem and what solution they have opted for.

Comment: This is hardly too broad, voting to reopen. It can be answered with a reasonably short answer to get the OP on the right architectural track (QED). It's one of the few not-entirely-trivial questions in this tag, come on.

Comment: @deceze People tend to use the "too broad" close reason for questions that ask how to write code that does such-and-such without showing an attempt and identifying a specific problem, ever since the "questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem..." reason was dropped. I think this is one of the many cases that demonstrate a point I tried to make on meta at the time, that while one might argue that "too broad" *semantically* encompasses such questions, it's confusing because it doesn't convey the right message about the real reason the question was closed.

Answer (score 2):

All you really need is to:

- be able to create an id, which in your case should probably be globally unique
- associate that id with your regular user's id
- be able to track that a unique id belongs to a topic

You can do this easily with one extra table:

```
table anonymous_ids
-------------------
user_id      INT    (references your user id)
anonymous_id VARCHAR, UNIQUE index
topic_id     INT    (references your threads/topic id)
```

When a user replies in a topic, you check whether there's already an anonymous id for him in this topic:

```sql
SELECT anonymous_id
  FROM anonymous_ids
 WHERE user_id  = {userId}
   AND topic_id = {topicId}
```

If there is no such id yet, you create it. That's the basic gist of it.

Comment: Do you think it would be appropriate to use the uniqid PHP function to generate the anonymous ID ?

Comment: But why don't you just do it in a single table with columns user_id, anonymous_id, and topic_id ? And I would generate the anonymous id based on time() and user_id and topic_id.

Comment: @Monsieur Depends on what kind of id you want. Using a simple auto_incrementing column and SO's format of *user123456* is perfectly fine IMO. If you want random strings, I'd probably rather read from `/dev/urandom` instead (on \*NIX). Or maybe even UUIDs. Consider that as that table fills up, it will get harder and harder to *randomly* create a new unique id which has never been generated before. You may have to use multiple tries after a while, which is not good. As such, use a really good random source, a really long id or a simple counter.

Comment: @Markus Indeed, why don't I? *BrettvorKopf*

Comment: @MarkusKottländer and decez thanks for your answers guys. I realize now that there is no real standard way of generating the ID and I can use whatever is more suited to my users.